# Best method to store and retrieve data using multiple keys

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

As part of an application being developed in "C" language, clients would be sending requests with two 16-byte values and some data. One of the two 16-byte values is the per client UID and the other being some random unique object UID. So, server would be receiving below kind of data from clients:

**From client1:**
<Client UID1, obj UID1, random-data>

**From client2:**
<Client UID2, obj UID4, random-data>

**From client3:**
<Client UID3, obj UID5, random-data>

Upon receiving above information, server needs to store them in a kind of table and respond a 8-byte unique ID for each such request. Clients will come back to server using either the combination of <Client UID, Obj UID> or the unique 8-byte ID (generated by server) to operate on the random data associated with the <Client UID, Obj UID>.

As number of such requests received would be humongous, I cannot store them in an array and use the index as the 8-byte unique ID. Also it would force me to do linear kind of search for identifying the matching <Client UID, Obj UID>.

So, can I know how to organize the data in an efficient manner so that I would be able to index using both 8-byte unique ID and the combination of both <Client UID, Obj UID>?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need to use [hash-table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), and store/lookup data here.
It is very quick for add or update record.
If you using [double hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_hashing) algorithm, you can use hashtable index as a `unique 8-byte ID`, to direct access into table cell without search. Of course, that index will be less than 8 bytes, but I think, you can pad it with 0s or so on.

You can get as basis my own double hash implementation in [emerSSL](https://github.com/emercoin/emcssh/blob/master/source/htable.c) project.